# Astronaut in cryogenic sleep is woken by all-female village, villagers become violent

Tags: story-identification, tv

An astronaut in cryogenic sleep is woken by a village of women. These women have lived for years with no men. As the man becomes integrated into the village women begin to act violently, mostly in jealousy over the men. It turns out there were other capsules and other men and in every village where they were placed women became violent. The man was placed back into cryogenic sleep for the safety of the female civilization.

Comment: When did you see this? It's a TV show? When did it appear to be made?

Comment: It was an episode of the Court Limits.... See answer from Richard.

Comment: Sounds like a [Genesis II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_%28film%29)/[Planet Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_%28film%29) story... When John Saxon gets captured by Diana Muldaur and her savage Amazons!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Outer Limits episode "[Lithia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithia_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)"

> ***"Lithia"** is set in 2055, in a world populated only by women. Almost all the previous population was killed years earlier in a war,
> followed by a plague that killed the remaining men.*
>
> *The women are
> living in a commune, and seem to be living full and happy lives,
> although they must work very hard, lacking some of the technology of
> the past. Neighboring villages have many of the resources, all in
> control of a council governing their use and trade. When a neighboring
> village refuses to defy the council and trade electricity prior to
> completion of an impact study, Mercer tells the women living in his
> commune that they must make sure that they have enough resources for
> themselves. Their leader tells him that kind of thinking is what led
> to war, she being the only woman old enough to remember. Intrigued by
> her memory, children ask her to tell of the man she loved before the
> war.*
>
> *Mercer becomes aggressive and proceeds to steal electricity from
> a rival village, enlisting help from a woman he becomes romantically
> involved with. Unfortunately, this leads to the deaths of several
> different women when the other village first tries to stop him, then
> tries to get the better of a prisoner trade with the woman who helped
> Mercer. After the funeral of the women from the village, it is
> revealed that the council was responsible for unfreezing eleven other
> men and attempting to integrate them into their society, but each
> attempt resulted in a similar tragedy. Moments before Mercer is
> refrozen, Hera, the leader of Lithia, calls him by his first name,
> Jason. Pleading for his life as he is about to be refrozen, Mercer is
> confused as to how she would know that, but, as she looks at her
> locket containing a picture of Mercer, we realize that he is the same
> Jason whom she loved before he was initially frozen during the war."*

There's a few minutes of the opening [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xqkrwr_lithia-opening-3-july-1998_shortfilms) and if you're in the US, you can watch the full episode online [here](http://www.hulu.com/watch/68273).

Comment: Thank you so much...this show has stuck in my mind for years.

Comment: @Tracy - http://youtu.be/CtNb1dnEaSQ?t=11s

Comment: @Tracy If this is the correct answer please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: There's also the twist of who the female village leader is!